# How can I set bandwidthProfile on flutter programmable-video

Tags: flutter, twilio

I want to use bandwidthProfile on flutter.
https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/tutorials/using-bandwidth-profile-api

But I cannot find the way to set it on flutter

this part should be the place to set it.
https://gitlab.com/twilio-flutter/programmable-video/-/blob/master/programmable_video/lib/src/programmable_video.dart#L189

but ConnectOptions does not have bandwidthProfile on its parameter

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The [Twilio Video Flutter project](https://gitlab.com/twilio-flutter/programmable-video/) is a community maintained Flutter wrapper, so it may not include all the functionality the official Twilio SDKs have. However, the project is open source so your best bet is to [raise an issue requesting the feature](https://gitlab.com/twilio-flutter/programmable-video/-/issues) or contribute the feature to the project yourself.